# DataSource to TabPage?

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

I'm pretty new in programming and i'm currently working on a order system. I made a local database and i want my tables that i've wrote down to show up in the tab sector.

[image: The tab sector i want it in]

And i wanted them to look just like in the table design but i don't even know how to put them in the tab sector in my system design.

[image: what i want to do in a (crappy) edited image]

Comment: Put a DataGridView control on the TabPage?

Comment: ok, i'll try that!